# How change delimiter for "toString" in R?

Tags: r, shiny

There is a great R function "toString" with "," as a delimiter by default.

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 1, 2, 3),
  y = c("11", "12", "2", "3"))

df %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(y_str = toString(y)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

How to change it for any value like "br" that is necessary for web app.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use `paste()` with `collapse = "br"`.

Comment: The source code of `toString.default` is quite simple. You could modify it and create your own function without a hard-coded separator.

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use `paste` or `paste0`:

```
a <- 11; b <- 12; c <- 2; d <- 3
paste0(a, b, c, d)
# [1] "111223"
paste(a, b, c, d, sep=" ")
# [1] "11 12 2 3"
```

You cannot get the result directly from toString even though toString uses paste under the hood:

```
toString.default
# function (x, width = NULL, ...) 
# {
#     string <- paste(x, collapse = ", ")
# --- function continues ---
```